# How do I pass a string parameter to Powershell for ConvertFrom-StringData from command line?

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble running powershell with a script that should use a variable number of parameters.

The script file looks like this:

```
param( [string]$paramString )

$params = ConvertFrom-StringData $paramString
$params
```

Running the script directly in powershell yields the expected result:

```
[PS] C:\some\path>.\test.ps1 "a=foo `n b=bar `n c=moo"

Name                           Value
----                           -----
c                              moo
a                              foo
b                              bar
```

Calling powershell from the command line with the same script and parameters shows this:

```
C:\some\path>powershell -nologo -file ./test.ps1 "a=foo `n b=bar `n c=moo"

Name                           Value
----                           -----
a                              foo `n b=bar `n c=moo
```

It seems like the passed string is in some format so the `ConvertFrom-StringData` function is unable to parse it anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Approach with `-File` is problematic because the parameter is not evaluated by cmd (at it is in PowerShell) and new lines equivalents are not expanded, they are passed in literally.

The problem can be solved if we still let PowerShell to do that by using `-Command` instead:

```
powershell -nologo -command "./test.ps1 ""a=foo `n b=bar `n c=moo"""
```

It is ugly: we have to double every inner `"` in the command. But it works. (The command can be defined by several parameters; I just prefer to use a single parameter: this way looks simpler to me).

Comment: Thanks Roman, that worked. Just an addendum for another thing: I had a second parameter for the script that contained a string that should be used literally. Using ""param1"" ""a=foo `n b=bar `n c=moo"" resulted in both strings getting concatenated. I had to use 'param1' ""a=foo `n b=bar `n c=moo"" to get it to work as intended.

Comment: Yeah... Calling PowerShell scripts with complex parameters from cmd is painful. If it is know at design time that a script is for calls from cmd then its input interface should be designed as simple as possible. Consider this advice, too, because the approach with `-Command` does not cover all use cases of the `-File` approach.

Answer (score -1):

Use single quote to pass parameters to powershell with script like this:

```
C:\some\path>powershell .\test.ps1 'a=foo' 'b=bar' 'c=moo'
```